# The '.is if' handler of pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys

Let us start with an example from the pgf manual, version 2.10, page 495:

```
\pgfkeys{/flat world/.is if=theworldisflat}
\pgfkeys{/flat world=false}
\def\x#1{% code-A
  \iftheworldisflat
    Flat
  \else
    Round?
  \fi
  #1%
}
```

I have two questions concerning this example.

(1) Can I set `\newif\iftheworldisflat` within the command `\pgfkeys` or, better still, get `\pgfkeys` to declare the boolean for me automatically. The latter is what obtains in *xkeyval* package.

(2) How do I pass a code (eg, code-A above) directly to the key `flat world` within `\pgfkeys` without a de tour? Is this possible? Something like the following appears to me to be better, since it allows the callback to be executed whenever the key is set.

```
\pgfkeys{%
  /my family/my keys/.cd,
  keya/.is if={<boolean>}{<callback>},
}
```

(3) Why did *pgfkeys* use `\edef` here:

```
\def\pgfkeys@non@outer@newif@#1#2{%
   \expandafter\edef\csname #2true\endcsname
     {\noexpand\let\noexpand#1=\noexpand\iftrue}%
   \expandafter\edef\csname #2false\endcsname
     {\noexpand\let\noexpand#1=\noexpand\iffalse}%
   \csname #2false\endcsname
}
```

**EDIT**

What I have tried is for something like the following. I am still thinking of how to optimize the code; that's why I am yet to post it:

```
\pgfkeys{%
  /my family/my keys/.cd,
  keya/.is if=boola,
  keyb/.is if=keyb, % Acceptable, but why repeat 'keyb'?
  % Use 'keyc' as the boolean and allow the user to provide a default value.
  % No need to provide a boolean or repeat 'keyc' on the right hand side of '='.
  keyc/.is bool={true}{\def\y##1{##1-True-#1}}{\def\y##1{##1-False-#1}},
}
```

Comment: `\edef` there is not needed, of course. Change `\edef` into `\def` and remove all `\noexpand` tokens: it will behave exactly the same. At least if `\let`, `\iftrue` and `\iffalse` are the primitives when the code is executed: I don't think they are ever redefined.

Comment: @AhmedMusa: That edit changes the question quite considerably.  Originally it had the flavour of "How do I do this?" but now it reads "I can do this, what should I be aware of?".  The two are *very* different.  I, for one, would not have attempted answering the second!  Though I would be (am) very interested in the answer.  If you could explain a little more when asking your questions it would be really helpful.  I find that I mentally sort questions into "Questions where I might be able to help" and "Questions where I might learn something". If you add a bit more context, it would help a lot.

Comment: Good.  Now that I've figured you out (in a manner of speaking), I'm looking forward to learning from your questions.

Answer (score 13):

Unlike `xkeyval`, `pgfkeys` is designed to work not only with LaTeX. In the plain format, `\newif` is outer, and so it cannot (easily) be used within `\pgfkeys`. Thus you have to set up your `\if...` macros outside of keyval set up with `pgfkeys`.

On the second question, that is not how the `.is if` handler works. You could of course redefine it (very risky), or more safely create your own handler to do what you want.

On the third part, using `\noexpand` inside an `\edef` is one way to get outer control sequences into other macros, something that is usually not allowed. Once again, this is a safety precaution more for plain TeX than LaTeX or ConTeXt.

Comment: *pgfkeys* has LaTeX-style `\pgfkeys@non@outer@newif`. Thanks, I will just define my own new handler.

Comment: @AhmedMusa But let us know about your handler!

Comment: I still don't understand *why* the `\edef`: it's `\newif` that's outer, but it's not used there and, for instance, `\expandafter\def\csname #1true\endcsname{\let#1=\iftrue}` is exactly the same as what's obtained with the `\edef`.

Comment: @egreg But what if `#1` is define and is outer? My take is that is why the `\edef` is used.

Comment: Who would define `\ifxyz` as outer?

Comment: @egreg No idea! I did not say it is necessary to do this: I did say 'safety precaution'. There are no comments in the source for this macro, so I guess that you'd have to ask Christian F. for a definitive answer.

Comment: Oh. I see my name here. Did I write that method? I do not remember any particular reason for an `\edef`. The only thing I remember is that I once stumbled over the `\outer` problem in some plain-text compatibility problem and fixed it somehow. I remember vaguely that I copy-pasted code from somewhere else. I also know that some portions of pgf use `\csname .. \endcsname` since such constructions seem to ignore `\outer` flags.

Answer (score 9):

I've also thought for a long time for a better `.is if` solution that does not require me to invent a new name every time that I want to create a new boolean option: `/my package/fancy option` already *is* quite a nice name, doesn't clash with other packages, and is definitely better than writing `\if@mpkg@@fan@opt` everywhere. Furthermore, as a nice added plus, you can also define options which make the value of a toggle depend on another toggle (see example bellow).

Building on top of `etoolbox` toggles, I've implemented my solution as a new `.is toggle` handler, and created a small package [ezkeys](https://github.com/navarroj/ezlatex/blob/master/ezkeys.sty) which is basically a single file with lots of comments and a bit of code defining a few new pgfkey handlers.

As an example usage, toggles are defined using

```
\pgfkeys{
  my package/.is family,
  my package,
  numbered/.is toggle,
  in toc/.is toggle,
  in toc/if numbered/.code = \linktoggle{/my package/in toc}{/my package/numbered}
}
```

Options are then selected as usual

```
\pgfkeys{
  my package,
  numbered = false,
  in toc = if numbered % will be true or false depending on `numbered`
}
```

And then one can write conditionals such as:

```
\iftoggle{/my package/numbered}{numbered is true}{numbered is false}
\iftoggle{/my package/in toc}{in toc is true}{in toc is false}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are my proposed `.is if` handlers. The code at [pgfkeys-patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51336/can-pgfkeys-deal-with-active-comma) is required for the following to compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgfkeys-patch}
\makeatletter
% Syntaxes:
% <key>.is if with no callback=<default>
% <key>.is if with 1 callback={<default>}{<callback>}
% <key>.is if with 2 callbacks={<default>}{<callback-1>}{<callback-2>}
% In this way I know I am dealing with <key> alone, and not with another 
% (auxiliary) boolean as in the conventional '.is if' handler.
\pgfkeys{%
  /handlers/.is if with no callback/.code={%
    \pgfkeys@boolean@handler{#1}{##1}{}{}%
  },
  /handlers/.is if with 1 callback/.code 2 args={%
    \pgfkeys@boolean@handler{#1}{##1}{#2}{}%
  },
  /handlers/.is if with one callback/.style 2 args={%
    \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.is if with 1 callback={#1}{#2}%
  },
  /handlers/.is if with 2 callbacks/.code n args={3}{%
    \pgfkeys@boolean@handler{#1}{##1}{#2}{#3}%
  }
}
\def\pgfkeys@savresname#1{%
  \ifcase#1\relax
    \let\pgfkeyssavedkey=\pgfkeyscurrentkey
    \let\pgfkeyssavedname=\pgfkeyscurrentname
    \edef\pgfkeyssavedpath{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
    \edef\pgfkeyscurrentkey{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
    \pgfkeys@split@path
    \let\pgfkeyssavednameb\pgfkeyscurrentname
  \or
    \let\pgfkeyscurrentkey=\pgfkeyssavedkey
    \let\pgfkeyscurrentname=\pgfkeyssavedname
    % Don't do \edef\pgfkeyscurrentpath{\pgfkeyssavedpath} here, since
    % \pgfkeyscurrentpath is determined by \pgfkeys@pathtoks.
  \else
    \pgfkeys@error{Number '#1' out of range [0,1]}%
  \fi
}
\def\pgfkeys@boolean@handler#1#2#3#4{%
  \pgfkeys@savresname{0}%
  % Let's not redefine 'if\pgfkeyscurrentname' if it already exists,
  % so that we don't change its current state:
  \ifpgfkeyscsdef{if\pgfkeyscurrentname}{}{%
    % Can use \outer-defined \newif:
    \csname newif\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname if\pgfkeyscurrentname\endcsname        
  }%
  \begingroup
  \def\reserved@a{\pgfkeyssavedpath/.code=}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\pgfkeysalso\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\reserved@a\expandafter\pgfkeys@boolean@handler@b
      \expandafter{\pgfkeyssavednameb}{#2}{#3}{#4},
    \pgfkeyssavedpath/.default=#1%
  }%
  \pgfkeys@savresname{1}%
}
\def\pgfkeys@boolean@handler@b#1#2#3#4{%
  \ifpgfkeysxin{,\pgfkeystrimspace{#2},}{,true,false,}{%
    \ifpgfkeyscsdef{#1#2}{%
      \csname#1#2\endcsname
      \ifpgfkeysblank{#3#4}{}{\ifpgfkeysbool{#1}{#3}{#4}}%
    }{%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/errors/boolean expected/.@cmd}%
        \pgfkeyscurrentkey{#2}\pgfeov
    }%
  }{%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/errors/boolean expected/.@cmd}%
      \pgfkeyscurrentkey{#2}\pgfeov
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Examples:

```
\pgfkeys{%
  /my family/.cd,
  flatworlda/.is if with no callback=true,
  flatworldb/.is if with 1 callback={true}{\def\x##1{##1T#1}},
  flatworldc/.is if with 2 callbacks={false}{\def\x##1{##1T#1}}{\def\x##1{##1F#1}},
  % pgfkeys package doesn't seem to like the idea of optional argument, otherwise I
  % would have preferred something like the following, in which the default 
  % value 'true' is optional:
  % flatworlda/.is if with no callback=[true]
}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/my family/flatworlda=false}
\pgfkeys{/my family/flatworldb=true}
\pgfkeys{/my family/flatworldc=false}
\edef\x{%
%  \ifflatworlda
  \ifflatworldb
%  \ifflatworldc
    Is flat%
  \else
    Is round%
  \fi
}
\pgfkeys{/my family/flatworldb=true}
\ifflatworldb
  true
\else
  false
\fi
\end{document}
```