# Is there a trick to reduce the number of counters in the following case?

Tags: loops

I want to avoid using `\tmp`. Is it possible to remove it while keeping the same output?

[image]

```
% Declare counters.
\newcount\pages% \pages is given so you cannot remove it!
\newcount\x
\newcount\tmp

% Initializing.
\pages=9% Try it for an odd or even integer.
\tmp=\pages
\advance\tmp by 1
\x=1

\loop
    \ifnum\x<\tmp
    \noindent\hfill\the\x
    \advance\x by 1
    \ifnum\x>\pages
        \hfill\null\endgraf
    \else
        \hfill\the\x\hfill\null\endgraf
    \fi
    \advance\x by 1
\repeat

\bye
```

Note: Please don't use `e-TeX` extension as I am learning Knuth's original TeX right now.

Comment: It might be handy to specify if a solution can use the e-TeX extensions, or has to stick to Knuth's TeX only.

Comment: @HiggsBoson: Not that it doesn't feel sort of like cheating, but still: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60099/who-doesnt-use-e-tex

Comment: @RyanReich: OK. Thanks. I will learn the extension later after grasping Knuth's original TeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with `\x=0`, step it as soon as possible and invert the inner conditional:

```
\newcount\pages % \pages is given so you cannot remove it!
\newcount\x

% Initializing.
\pages=9 % Try it for an odd or even integer.
\x=0

\loop
  \ifnum\x<\pages
  \advance\x by 1
  \noindent\hfill\the\x
  \ifnum\x<\pages
    \advance\x by 1
    \hfill\the\x
  \fi
  \hfill\null\endgraf
\repeat

\bye
```

Comment: The most compact solution!

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with simply testing for equality at the end of the loop:

```
% Declare counters.
\newcount\pages% \pages is given so you cannot remove it!
\newcount\x

% Initializing.
\pages=9 % Try it for an odd or even integer.

\x=1 %

\loop
  \ifnum\x=\pages
    \noindent
    \hfill
    \number\x
    \hfill
    \null
    \endgraf
  \fi
  \ifnum\x<\pages
    \noindent
    \hfill
    \number\x
    \advance\x by 1 %
    \hfill
    \number\x
    \hfill
    \null
    \endgraf
    \advance\x by 1 %
\repeat

\bye
```

(I've added in a few spaces to correctly terminate numbers.)

Comment: `\pages=1` does not work. :-)

Comment: @HiggsBoson I've updated the answer to cover the no-loop case.

Comment: Defining `\printpage` seems to be unnecessary. Why don't you put its body directly into the first `\ifnum`?

Comment: @HiggsBoson Oops: I was experimenting with a few approaches, and forgot that I could remove that auxiliary!

Comment: Sorry, I switched to egreg's solution because of the minimal number of used characters.

Answer (score 4):

You got rid of `\tmp` in your answer, this removes `\x` as well.

```
% Declare counters.
\newcount\pages% \pages is given so you cannot remove it!

% Initializing.
\pages=9% Try it for an odd or even integer.


\def\z#1{%
\ifnum#1<\numexpr\pages+1\relax
    \noindent\hfill#1%
  \ifnum#1=\pages
        \hfill\null\endgraf
    \else
        \hfill\number\numexpr#1+1\hfill\null\endgraf
    \fi
    \expandafter\z\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+2\expandafter\relax\expandafter}%
\fi}
\z1
\bye
```

Comment: Who can compile it? I cannot.

Comment: @HiggsBoson Works for me (needs the e-TeX extensions, of course)

Comment: @David: Please why did you use `\repeat` in place of `\fi`. If I insert `\loop` in your conditionals, I will end up with a mess. Also, braces aren't expandable. So you have more than necessary number of `\expandafter`. I withdrew from editing your answer, but my name is still hanging in there.

Comment: `\repeat` is a mistake forgot to change it from the OP's version, of course it worked as it is defined to be `\fi` but would break a loop as you say. Will edit. The `\expandafter` is not expanding the brace but the token _after_ it, it is needed to expand the `\fi/\repeat` token before iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\numexpr\pages+1\relax` seems to work:

### Code:

```
% Declare counters.
\newcount\pages% \pages is given so you cannot remove it!
\newcount\x
%\newcount\tmp

% Initializing.
\pages=9% Try it for an odd or even integer.
%\tmp=\pages
%\advance\tmp by 1
\x=1

\loop
    \ifnum\x<\numexpr\pages+1\relax
    \noindent\hfill\the\x
    \advance\x by 1
    \ifnum\x>\pages
        \hfill\null\endgraf
    \else
        \hfill\the\x\hfill\null\endgraf
    \fi
    \advance\x by 1
\repeat

\bye
```

Comment: No performance drawback?

Comment: @HiggsBoson: I don't know. That would have to be measured.  Just like any other software I would assume that if you are reducing your memory requirements, you are probably increasing the compute time.

Comment: Judging performance with these things can be complex: assignments have a time requirement but so do expressions and expansion, so you have to test the real use cases. Lots of assignments will normally be slower than a small number of expressions, but one assignment _versus_ one expression is more difficult!